# How to get scroll up vs. down in R

Tags: r

I am using `getGraphicsEventEnv` to get events over an R plot. Previously, scroll up or down were encoded in the event handler but now, the test code posted on a [related bug fix](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16700) returns an empty whether it is scroll up or scroll down.

Is there a new way to get those events?

example code:

```
mousemove <- function (buttons, x, y){
    cat("mousemove")
    print(buttons)
    NULL
}
mouseclick <- function (buttons, x, y){
    cat("mouseclick")
    print(buttons)
    NULL
}
mouserelease <- function (buttons, x, y){
    cat("mouserelase")
    print(buttons)
    NULL
}
keystroke <- function (key){
    cat("keystroke")
    print(key)
    NULL
}

if (identical(version$os, "linux-gnu")){
    x11(type = "Xlib")
} else {
    x11()
}
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot.new()
getGraphicsEvent(onMouseMove = mousemove, onMouseDown = mouseclick, onMouseUp = mouserelease, onKeybd = keystroke)
```

On scroll this selects both mouseclick and mouserelease on a loop but with no buttons given, impossible to use. Before, on X11, we had special "buttons" returned for "scroll up" and "scroll down". To me this is a regression, hopefully replaced by a feature somewhere but where is the feature?

Comment: Could you fill in a reproducible example here?

Comment: Hard to tell. You offer no code.